# Merge the rows and give me the total count

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, count, group-by

I want to count how many unique games a user have been played. Here's how the current SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.id_game) AS c
FROM discord AS d
JOIN discord_games AS dg
ON d.id_game = dg.id
WHERE d.id_user = '1'
AND d.id_game != '0'
GROUP BY d.id_game
ORDER BY dg.data_name ASC
```

And here's now the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discord` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_channel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_game` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_suppressed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_logged` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discord_games` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discord_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id` text NOT NULL,
  `data_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_avatar` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

The SQL query counts correctly but it only counts 1 per row.

**Example of how I'm thinking.** If the user with the ID 1 have played the same game 24 times (for an example Battlefield 3) it will return 1 played game. If the same user plays another game 37 times, it will return 2 played games and so on.

`SUM(DISTINCT ...` doesn't work since it only replace 1 with the game ID.

How can I sum the rows so it displays the number 2 instead of 2 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove the group by property and count the distinct games played. It will return the number of distinct gamesp layed by the user 1

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.id_game) AS c
FROM discord AS d
JOIN discord_games AS dg
ON d.id_game = dg.id
WHERE d.id_user = '1'
AND d.id_game != '0'
ORDER BY dg.data_name ASC
```

Comment: Oh my! You're right! Too many hours with this code :P Many thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as I can.